# Unable to import a local project to another local one by absolute path:

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have 2 projects in **the different directories**, one of them I want to import to another one. Say, the project I want to import has this:

```
/path123/my_project/main_folder/file1.py
/path123/my_project/main_folder/file2.py
/path123/my_project/main_folder/file3.py
```

Here's what I did in the 2nd project:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path123/my_project/main_folder')
# it's indeed inserted 

import main_folder.file1            # error - not found
from main_folder import file1       # error - not found
import my_project.main_folder.file1 # error - not found
```

Answer (score 1):

After you appended the path where your second python file that you want to use in your first python file is you directly import the module by its filename without the extension. For example

```
import file1
```

Every location in your `sys.path` is then looked for the file `file1.py` to import.

Say you have your main python program in `/prog1/main.py` and you want to import the file from `/prog2/lib/want_to_import.py` in your `main.py` it should look like

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/prog2/lib')
import want_to_import
```

Comment: it's 2 different projects.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp You append the path like you do in your question but import it my way

Comment: One more question: if I want to import `file1` to each module of `project2`. Do I have to put the code `import sys
sys.path.append('/path123/my_project/main_folder')` in `project2/__init__.py` file?